# $modal window will not open when called in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

So first off let me explain the project I am working on. The end goal is to develop a web app used to check the status of a branch on source control. This solution would be a lot easier to use for those in my company that do not understand all the ins and outs of our version control system.

My system is using d3.js to create a collapsible tree layout to represent each branch and its corresponding parents and/or children. The user will be able to drill down to the branch they would like to check the status on and select it by clicking. Upon a click, an angular modal window will appear. This modal window will have a template that I have created, named "propertyBox.html".

My problem currently is that when clicking the last branch to display info, the modal window will not pop up. I have searched for 2 days at other S.O. articles trying to fix this problem. I've tried making sure to use the correct version of the angular ui-bootstrap and the correct version of bootstrap.css but to no avail. Everything I have tried gives me some sort of console error.

This is the current console errors I get are:

`GET http://localhost/versioncontrolviewer/usingD3/function%20(a,b)%7Breturn%20b.templateUrl%7C%7C%22template/modal/window.html%22%7D 403 (Forbidden)                 angular.min.js:99 <blah blah blah> t.onreadystatechange                                   angular.min.js:99

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function                         angular.min.js:98 
p                                                                       angular.min.js:99                       t.onreadystatechange                                                   angular.min.js:98`

Because I am using d3, I am not using ng-click on the childmost node. Instead, I am detecting if there are no more children(in which case it would be the childmost). That is when I am triggering the modalOpen function. At one point I was able to at least hit a breakpoint in my new controller telling me it made it there but there was still no modal present. All I ever get is a grey background.

I'd appreciate any help in regards to how to set up and use the modal. Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

I've just found that if I use bootstrap.css version 3.0 it will never reach my controller. However if i use the 2.2.2 version, I do end up in my called controller but still no modal window and still the same js console errors.

Code is located here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RsrVxwdEriTV4hAit7tt

Comment: Can you replicate it in a Plunker? Would be much easier to help.

Comment: Yeah sorry... Here ya go. http://plnkr.co/edit/RsrVxwdEriTV4hAit7tt . If you open the output in its own window and then use the debugger tools you can see the errors i'm getting